# Subquery in a loop

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Need some help finding out the best way to get results from this kind of query efficiently, I have a table of messages and this table of messages has comments for each of them. I need to retrieve each message and each subsequent comment for the message. At first I was thinking to grab all the messages and their PK, then within a loop use this to get the comments, but I am wondering if there is a more efficient way to do that. I want each message to be displayed along with all subsequent comments for that message. Message1 -> all comments Message2 -> all comments.
This is an example of how I wanted the output to be like:

```
eg.    Work Site Maintenance.  //Message
               At 1pm          //comments
               At 2pm          //comments
               At 3pm          //comments
         Work Site Offline.
               Foundation work
               Layng blocks
               Placing steel
```

My current query to get the list of messages but not comments for each

```
SELECT MS.status_id,
       MS.member_id,
       MS.status_text,
      MS.status_time
    FROM message_status MS
    WHERE MS.member_id = memberId //variable
    ORDER BY MS.status_id DESC 
    LIMIT 20


**message_status**
status_id PK
member_id
status_text
status_time

**comments_status**
status_id FK
member_id FK
comm_text
comm_time
```

Comment: so the `Work Site Maintenance` part shall be the expected result?

Comment: correct, would like it to be displayed in that format, Work Site Maintenance then the comment associated to this message.

Comment: How are comments and messages related? From your structure above,, doesn't seem they are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can just join them to get the result you want.

```
SELECT MS.status_id,
   MS.member_id,
   MS.status_text,
   MS.status_time,
   CS.comm_text,
   CS.comm_time
FROM message_status MS
  left join comments_status CS on CS.status_id = MS.status_id
WHERE MS.member_id = memberId //variable
ORDER BY MS.status_id DESC, CS.comm_time DESC
LIMIT 20
```

Comment: I suggest a left join to comments, in case some messages don't have any.

Comment: works, but i forgot to mention that each message can have multiple comments, I wanted only one message to be displayed then all its comments. Message1 -> all comments Message2 -> all comments. With this solution it repeats the message for each comment that is found.

Comment: That is the nature of the resultset. You will need to implement the custom output that you describe via the application code. It is a "master-detail" relationship. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master%E2%80%93detail_interface

Answer (score 1):

How about using [LEFT JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/left-join-optimization.html):

```
SELECT MS.status_id,
       MS.member_id,
       MS.status_text,
       CS.comm_text,
      MS.status_time
    FROM message_status MS
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM comments_status) AS CS
    USING (status_id,member_id)
    WHERE MS.member_id = memberId //variable
    ORDER BY MS.status_id DESC 
    LIMIT 20;
```

Also, indexing the columns on WHERE and JOIN clauses should speed up the SELECT query (but slow down the INSERT, so it's a trade-off only worth if you perform this query quite often):

```
CREATE INDEX m_id ON message_status (member_id);
CREATE INDEX sm_id ON message_status (status_id,member_id);
CREATE INDEX sm_id ON comments_status (status_id,member_id);
```

Example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/565f9/1

Answer (score 0):

The optimal choice is get all the data in one roundtrip with a join versus the overhead of a roundtrip to a smaller amount of data many times.

With no usage context you can argue this either way.

The things to look at, are.

Do you always want to get all the data?

Do you need all the data before you can do the next thing you want to do with it.

What's the cost of a round trip?

What's the cost of getting it all?

Would caching the data once you had (e.g. lazy loading be useful). You need to guess at how volatile the data is, ie. how likely is it that the cache is out of date, remember that get all the data in one go is a big cache.

It's mre than possible you might choose to be inefficient for say UI responsiveness. Think filling a combo with customer names and then showing it's properties on selection.
But then if was a web page, roundtrips even with something like ajax could be painful.

So in short, efficient at what?

Comment: Thanks for the insight as well, this data would be changed daily and will be accessed many times throughout the day by the members. When requested the messages must show the associated comments for it. Getting this data may be blocking to continue to then ext step if an additional change needs to be made. Not sure of the cost perse but the text fields are (VARCHAR 180)